# How to count words with multiple lines in C?

Tags: c

So i'm kind of stuck, counting spaces is no longer helpful because it always leaves one word un counted for. I can't start my variable off at 1 because what if there is no word at all.

This is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char ch;
    char character;
    char prvs;
    unsigned long int linecount = 0;
    unsigned long int charcount = 0;
    unsigned long int wordcount = 0;
    //int i = 0;

    while((character=getc(stdin)) != EOF){
        //char n[] ="\n";
        if(character== '\n'
            linecount += 1;
        /*
        if(character==' ' || character=='\n'){
            if(character=='\n'
                wordcount +=2;
            else
                wordcount += 1;
        }*/
        if(character != ' ' && prvs == ' ')
            wordcount += 1;
        charcount += 1;
        prvs = character;
    }//TEST
    printf("CHAR: %lu WORD: %lu LINE: %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount );
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the file im testing it against

```
hello world
hi there
bye
```

and this is my output

```
CHAR: 25 WORD: 2 LINE: 3
```

Comment: You should take into consideration that new words start after a '\n' also...

Comment: Think about the value of `prvs` at the beginning of each line and at the beginning of the input.

Comment: If \n is found you should also increment wordcount. You can check if the last read character was a letter/number and increse word by 1. I guess that would solve it hmm

Comment: You could use [isspace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isspace.3.html); you should not use the C++ tag, so please edit your question. At last, compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use a debugger** (`gdb`). Take the habit of initializing all your variables!

Comment: Take care to properly format and tag your question. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26637947/revisions to see what I changed and how. (look both at the markdown and at the rendered view)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
    if(!isspace(character) && isspace(prvs)){
```

instead of

```
    if(character != ' ' && prvs == ' '){
```

That will take care of counting words that start right after the newline. It will also take care of dealing with any tab characters existing in the input.

You'll also have to add logic to count the first word. To do that you can initialize `prev` as:

```
char prev = '\0';
```

and change the line

```
    if(!isspace(character) && isspace(prvs)){
```

to

```
    if(!isspace(character) && (isspace(prvs) || prvs == '\0') ){
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code works for me:

```
    int atLeastOneChar = 0;
    prvs = '/n';
    while((character=getc(stdin)) != EOF)
    {

        if(character== '\n')
        {
            ++linecount;
            if((prvs != '\n') && (prvs != ' ')) ++wordcount;
        }

        if((character == ' ') && (prvs != ' ' ) && (prvs != '\n' ))
        {
            ++wordcount;
        }           
        if((character != ' ') && (character != '\n' ))
        {
            atLeastOneChar = 1;
        }           
        charcount += 1;
        prvs = character;

     }//TEST
     if((atLeastOneChar == 1) && (wordcount == 0)) ++wordcount;

     printf("CHAR: %lu WORD: %lu LINE: %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount );
```